# How does PaddleOCR performance compare to Google Cloud Vision OCR API?

Tags: compare, ocr

Recently i find an OCR tool, which is called PaddleOCR. Has anyone used it, and how this OCR system preformance compare to Google Cloud Vision API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard PaddleOCR called itself an industry-level open-sourced OCR engine, so I test a few images between it and Google Cloud Vision.

Generally speaking, commercial APIs like Google Cloud and Azure suppose to work better than the open-sourced OCR engine, it does, but for some scenarios, it's not too far away.

If the text is clear and flat, both work great. The main difference is the result format. Google API gives you rich content including block, paragraph, and word location information. PaddleOCR only returns the result according to the text line (transcriptions and locations).

If your test images are more complicated, like curved text, handwriting, or blurry. Commercial APIs probably work great than the open-sourced engine. However, when it can not meet your needs, try to use PaddleOCR training a new model.

Here is some visualization images:

PaddleOCR:
[test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVnPP.jpg)
[test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7EjZ.png)

Google Cloud Vision API:
[test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL4PY.jpg)
[test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V41m7.jpg)